# How can I open my Meteor app's port to the local network

Tags: networking, localhost, port-forwarding

I'm running a MeteorJS app on `localhost:3000`. I'd like to allow other computers connected to my network access to view the app by visiting my IP address. Any ideas on how I can do this?

EDIT: I'm running Ubuntu 12.10, and I've also installed `nmap`, in case that's helpful.

EDIT 2: I've tried opening the port 3000 up, but I'm given an error saying it's already busy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I solved my problem. It had to do with the firewall. The command to make the port accessible on the local network ip (192.168 etc.) was: `sudo ufw allow [port-number]`.